# JQuery Change function not work with ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html code

```
<div class="gridRowsContainer">
<div ng-repeat="item in ActiveUserData.ListModel track by $index" class="">
<!-- Checkboxes Generated/inserted here by ajax  -->
<div class="gridRow pnl-no-dimiss" ng-style="getRowCss(item)" id="user_list_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div>
        <div class="userLight listViewRow">
            <div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
                <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" aria-invalid="false">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

My jQuery Code

```
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
 $(this).closest('[ng-repeat*="item"]').nextAll('[ng-repeat*="item"]:lt(3)').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
```

so it not working when content is loaded via ajax , any idea how to make it working when content is loaded via ajax on page load and also more checkboxes entries are loaded when user scroll down .

working jsfiddle with static checkboxes list :: https://jsfiddle.net/mmzth076/7/
but not work with ajax

Comment: where are you binding the change event? I'm assuming the elements are getting created as a result of the ajax response? If that is the case, you will need to bind the change after the elements are created and available in the DOM

Comment: Your jquery code is probably executed once, in the document ready handler, so it finds all checkboxes available at that moment and configures the change event handler for them. Regarding the html obtained in an ajax call, you probably insert it into the DOM at some moment. This is a good moment for setting up the change event handler for that new html as well.

Comment: can you tell me how can i bind checkbox change function

Comment: Just think about your jquery code as of a setup code, but not as of a declaration automatically applied to all the html code that exists now and appears in the future.

Comment: How are you trying to implement your AJAX call?

Comment: there is office 365 user page , which load more users on scroll down via ajax , so i was writing script for it to select checkboxes auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the change function in the success handler of the ajax:

```
$.ajax {
  method: 'GET',
  success: function() {
    load_grid(); //Code that builds the grid with the checkboxes
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
      $(this).closest('[ng-repeat*="item"]')
        .nextAll('[ng-repeat*="item"]:lt(3)')
        .find('[type="checkbox"]')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
  }
}
```

You can also use any known parent of the grid that is available in the DOM at the time of binding the click event handler.

```
$('body').on('change', ":checkbox", function () {
    $(this).closest('[ng-repeat*="item"]')
        .nextAll('[ng-repeat*="item"]:lt(3)')
        .find('[type="checkbox"]')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Replace body with any known predecessor at the time of binding.

Comment: i have no access to ajax functions of webpage , as am writing this script for office 365

Comment: Just updated my answer to use a known DOM element at the time of binding.

Answer (score 0):

When you load contain via ajax, it's it's not going to trigger the the changed event.  If you want to trigger, just use jquery and trigger the event manually.

```
$('checkboxyouwanttotrigger').trigger('change')
```